# Facebook API: checkin and status message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm about to start integrating Facebook in an Android native app. I'd want to be able to post into the user's wall giving her the possibility of attaching her location, what I was told that is possible to do from an Android app... but I need someone to explain what the difference between a checkin and a status message with an attached place is, because I couldn't make it clear by looking up in the Facebook API documentation... they are different objects, but they seem to have the same place info, and the checkin object has also a message field.

Could anybody help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want post to a wall its "wall feed". from the wall feed if u not given any user id in the sense it's like share the post in your own wall.

Comment: thanks, but I don't get the difference between checkin and status+place objects yet